# .each animate with random value

Tags: jquery, floating

I'm trying to make a few divs (which will be images of baloons) hover up and down but with random values so that they are not all going up and down together and look a little more floaty.

**Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/425/**

I've tried this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function runIt(i, hoverAmount) {      
        $('#baloon' + i).animate({top: '+=' + hoverAmount}, 1000);
        $('#baloon' + i).animate({top:'+=' + hoverAmount}, 1000, runIt);
        var currentBaloon = $('#baloon' + i);
        console.log('baloon: ' + currentBaloon);
    }

    var i = 1
    $('.baloon').each(function() {
        var hoverAmount = 15 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
        runIt(i, hoverAmount);
        i++;
    });
});
```

however, I keep getting this returned in the console:

```
baloon: [object Object]
```

can someone help me with this, I would like both the divs to move up and down randomly and look floaty.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to control `i` yourself, as an iterating int is passed into `each()` as the first parameter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i'm pretty new to JS, could you elaborate for me?

Comment: Is your only problem the fact that you're seeing that in the console, or are you not getting the effect you want either...?

Comment: what's the problem? I see the squares moving at different speed and not floating "togheter"

Comment: You may want to clarify what you're asking by editing the question, then.

Comment: `currentBaloon` is a jQuery object, so its correctly saying `[object Object]`. What value were you expecting there?

Comment: You're getting `[object Object]` in the console because you're appending a string an an object. This is normal behaviour. Your code is working though as the baloons animate correctly. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the baloons should float up and down and some go further down/up than others. A bit like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are calling the `runIt` functions without parameters:

```
$('#baloon' + i).animate({top:'+=' + hoverAmount}, 1000, runIt);
```

First of all you need to go up in the second call (so use `-=`), then you need to pass the same parameters to `runIt`:

```
$('#baloon' + i).animate({top: '-=' + hoverAmount}, 1000, function() {
    runIt(i, hoverAmount);
});
```

The `console.log` is another problem, you are logging an object so this is normal.

In terms of decent design, as @Rory McCrossan said, you have the element and the index already in jQuery, so you could simplify everything like this:

```
 function runIt(element, hoverAmount) {
     element.animate({top: '+=' + hoverAmount}, 1000);
     element.animate({top: '-=' + hoverAmount}, 1000, function() {
         runIt(element, hoverAmount);
     });
 }

 $('.baloon').each(function() {
     var hoverAmount = 15 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
     runIt($(this), hoverAmount);
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/427/